# java printing out an arraylist to build a sql sting

Tags: java, sql, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to build a SQL statement using a set of values from an array list.  I'll start from the beginning.

Define my arrayList

```
ArrayList<String[]> myRecords = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Define my array string:

```
String[] record = new String[2];
```

Then i loop though a file and split on on the comma and add the record to myRecords

```
while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            record = scan.nextLine().split(",");
            myRecords.add(record);
        }
```

So now I need to create an SQL import statement and use thoes values in the arraylist.  For example.

```
String sql = "insert into table (parm1, parm2) Values ";
```

Now I want to loop though the array and put fill in param1 & param2.

```
   for(String[] list : myRecords)
    {
       sqlString +=("(");
        for(String list1 : list)
        {
            sqlString +=("'"+ list1+ "',");
        }
        sqlString+=("),");
    }
        sqlString += ';';

    logger.info(sqlString);
```

The problem now is when I print out the SQL string it looks like this.

```
insert into table (parm1, parm2) Values ('value1','value2',),('value3','value4',),;
```

So on and so forth.

So the problem is that there is an extra comma in there at the end of value2 and value4.  And after the last bracket before the ;  I've gone switching it around etc, but I can't seem to figure out how i can get a proper formatted sql string.

This is how it should look.

```
 insert into table (parm1, parm2) Values ('value1','value2'),('value3','value4');
```

Perhaps it's the way I am forming my for loop.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I would suggest looking at [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Assuming your eventually applying that SQL to a db, it allows you accomplish what you are trying to achieve with a lot less code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter and initialize it to 0, increment the counter after added a value. Only append the comma when the counter is larger than 0

```
int recCount = 0;
for(String[] list : myRecords)
{
    if (recCount > 0)
    {
        sqlString += ",";
    }
    sqlString +=("(");
    int count = 0
    for(String list1 : list)
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            sqlString += ",";
        }
        sqlString += "'"+ list1+ "'";
        count++;
    }
    sqlString+=(")");
    recCount++;
}
```

Building SQL strings in general is not a great idea and is a major security risk

Comment: This one seemed to work the best.  the only issue is right at the very end there an extra comma.  So it does ),;  which is an invalid sql statement.  How do i get rid of the extra comma at the end

Comment: O, I see the problem... You need another flag a level higher up

Comment: Did you look at @jean-logeart solution? He uses a boolean flag instead of a counter.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
boolean first = true;
for(String[] list : myRecords) {
    if(first) {
        first = false;
    } else {
        sqlString += ',';
    }
    sqlString +=("(");
    for(String list1 : list) {
        sqlString +=("'"+ list1+ "',");
    }
    sqlString+=(")");   // no more "'"
}
sqlString += ';';
```

Comment: The issue I have with this one is ',),(' when it should be '),('  and at the end of the statement it show up as ',); when it should be ');